# Please explain how we get the equation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)B_{n+1}-B_n]=-1$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, bernoulli-numbers

Please explain how we get the equation $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)B_{n+1}-B_n]=-1$$ from the equation $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x-1]x^n=-1, \ x \in \Bbb Z, \ \  ........(1)$$

Here $B_n$ are Bernouli numbers, $B_0=1, \ B_1=-1/2, \ B_3=0, B_4=1/6, \cdots.$

**I have seen this within an article which  claims as follows:**

At first put $x=1$ in $(1)$ to get

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!n=-1$

and then  put $x=-1$ to get

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!(-1)^n(n+2)=1$.

Then the article claims $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)B_{n+1}-B_n]=-1$.

But how does the process goes in?

I could not understand the trick behind the claim starting from $(1)$.

Can you please check the claim?

Comment: @Botond, sorry my mistake. you are right. It  is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x-1]x^n=-1$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Umbra method?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus

Comment: @Phicar, No, I am not familiar but will see it. However if you can try for once on the above question

Comment: @user90369, can you leave your comment as answer please?

Comment: I suppose the equation lives on that, that differentiation or integration doesn't change anything of the equation in the end result (means: consistency). Since the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n (x)$ have the same property as $x^n$ in this respect, nothing of the method of proof changes by replacing $x^k$ by $B_k(x)$. With $x:=0$ the claim results. I think it helps, if you know the way of proof of the given equation.

Comment: @user90369, how your comments helps to prove the above claims in my question?

Comment: It' only a *note*! It would be an answer, if I proof something. My only intension was to give you an idea. The *umbral calculs* can help you too as mentioned by *Phicar*.

Comment: Try to proof the given equation, e.g. by integration. That's not difficult. Then substitute $x^k$ by $B_k(x)$ and try again. And: *Umbral calculus* is a bit strange, I don't know if it is allowed to substitute $x^k$ by the symbolic expression $(b+x)^k$ which is equivalent to $B_k(x)$ , I haven't tested. You can try. ;)

Comment: @user90369, ok i will try. thanks

Comment: If you use derivation, to proof the basic equation (with variable $x$): First multiply with $x$, then derivation, then multiply with $x$, then add $x-1$ .

Comment: @user90369, you mean integration of the equation $(1)$. That is, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x-1]x^n=-1  \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)x^{n+1}-x^n]=-1 \\  \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1) \int_{\Bbb Z} x^{n+1}dx- \int_{\Bbb Z} x^ndx]=- \int_{\Bbb Z} dx =-1 \ or \ -n \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n![(n+1)B_{n+1}(x)-B_n(x)]=-1 \ or \ -n$.                       $\text{Now putting $x=0$, we get Bernouli numbers instead of Bernoulin polynomials. Is is correct?}$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with $\int_{\mathbb{Z}}$ . Better to use derivation.

Comment: @user90369, I mean integration over the set of integers $\Bbb Z$. Please answer shortly what you are saying. I need it

Comment: Now it's o.k., please look at part $\text{(C)}$ of my text. I also show in details how to sum up. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Part* $\text{(C)}$ *is the solution.*

$\text{(A)}$

A possibility to show the consistency of the equation.

$\displaystyle f(x):=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty((n+1)!x^{n+1}-n!x^n)~$ with $~f(0)=-1$

$x(xf(x))'=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty((n+1)!x^{n+1}-n!x^n)=f(x)-(x-1)$

This works for $~f(x)=-1~$ under the condition $~f(0)=-1$ .

---

$\text{(B)}~~$ For all $~x\in\mathbb{N} :$

$\displaystyle –x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}f(k) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left( (n+1)!\frac{B_{n+2}(x)-B_{n+2}(0)}{n+2} - n!\frac{B_{n+1}(x)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1} \right)$

If it's also correct for $~x\in\mathbb{R} :$

$\displaystyle -1 = \frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left((n+1)!\frac{B_{n+2}(x)-B_{n+2}(0)}{n+2} - n!\frac{B_{n+1}(x)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\right)$

$\displaystyle\hspace{0.7cm} =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}(x)-n!B_n(x))$

*It remains to show*, that $~x\in\mathbb{R}~$ can be used instead of $~x\in\mathbb{N}~$ .

Perhaps the reason lies in the fact that the sum $~\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}f(k) ~$ is a polynomial

(here: of degree one) that is clearly defined by enough but finally many

(here: two) interpolation points.

---

$\text{(C)}~~$ *Solution.*

We use analytic continuation: $~\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n =\zeta(-n) = -\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}~$ , $~n\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$\displaystyle -1 = (f(x)-x+1)' = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty((n+1)!(n+1)x^n-n!nx^{n-1}) $

Sum up from $~k=1~$ to $~\infty~$ :

Left side: $~\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1) = -\zeta(0) = B_1$

Right side:

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (f(x)-x+1)'|_{x=k} = $

$\hspace{1cm}\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty((n+1)!(n+1)k^n-n!nk^{n-1})$

$\hspace{1cm}\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left((n+1)!(n+1)\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n\right)-n!n\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^{n-1}\right)\right) $

$\hspace{1cm}\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)!(n+1)\zeta(-n)-n!n \zeta(1-n))$

$\hspace{1cm}\displaystyle = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}-n!B_n)$

It follows:

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}-n!B_n) = -B_1~~~ | +(B_1-B_0)$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}-n!B_n) = -B_0 = -1$

q.e.d. :)

Comment: I still don't understand "integration over the set of integers" in your case, but beside that, something else: $n$ is a counter of the left side, therefore not usable for the right side.

Comment: Is part $~\text{(C)}~$ understandable?

Comment: Thanks. But  I could not understood the 2nd line from the last one

Comment: Do you mean $\zeta(.)$ , Riemann Zeta function ?

Comment: I mean the equation $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}-n!B_n) = -B_1~~~ | +(B_1-B_0)$. How did you get the RHS ?

Comment: The left side $~B_1~$ and the right side $~\displaystyle = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)!B_{n+1}-n!B_n)~$ are equal. Multiplicated by $~(-1)~$ you get the equation under "It follows:" .

Comment: Yes I got it . A lot of thanks. But finally I have one question. If the RHS (right side) of equation $(1)$ was $0$ instead of $-1$ in my question above, then can I follow same process ?

Comment: Not really, but if it works (you can test(!) it with the same process) then you can use it. But generally: What means $~\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 0~$ ? It's better to avoid that. ;)

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! It was a pleasure. :)

Comment: If you don't mind, i would say something. Can you please hide the answer? Because i want to use it in a portion of my work and as because there is a reason of plagiarism. But it is completely on your consent , if you permit

Comment: I can delete it, if you like. No problem. But everything what is written here can be used. It's not a plagiarism.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR : It's better *you* delete your question to avoid, that someone else starts again to answer. ;)

Comment: Ok, many thanks again. I will not use the answer and let it remain in this forum. It may help other. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe,yes. But have you tried to remove your question ?

Comment: Please, don't mix your questions. Simply open another question, then - me or someone else - will answer. ;)

Comment: No, I will not mix  with a new question. i just asked you that if you have p-adic number theory (little)  background then I  will send you my works just for checking or verifying by you. Thats what I said. I am sorry for mis-interprating

Comment: No, sorry, I don't check something extra (although I have not problems with p-adic numbers), because I don't know if I have enough time, which means: I don't like to promise to check something if I don't know if I can do it. --- Please simply open a new question, because 20 persons have more ideas then one! ;)

Comment: You are welcome. ;) --- If you open a question here, it would be good if you explain the background of the question so that the interested people here know what you like to know. :)